# Skype installation, but asked 2 times the password?

Tags: 14.04, software-center, skype

I just recently changed from Windows 8.1 to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, because I always wanted to be more safe in the internet, and also to avoid things like virus.

Today, to test if I knew some basic commands, I reinstalled Ubuntu, then I started to add my programs.
But, some programs, like Steam and Skype, I had to use the Ubuntu Software Center to install.

For Steam, i downloaded the .deb file then I installed it via Ubuntu Software Center, no problem.

For skype, I tried to get the .deb file, but after installing it, there wasn't a Skype Icon on the task bar, so I removed it and reinstalled the version from Ubuntu Software center. 
But, when I clicked to install it, it asked for my password (just like always) and I wrote in the box, but the installation didn't started. Then I clicked in the install button again, it asked 1 more time to write my password, I wrote it and the installation started.

Before using Linux, I always have been paranoid about my PC being infected, invaded, etc.

So, I would like to ask if what happened is some kind of bug, or if my PC have been compromised?

PS: Before installing anything, I did all updates (including security ones).

Thank you guys for helping me. Also, I loved the Ubuntu, I don't think I will use Windows again :D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The additional authentication prompt *should* not be any cause for concern. There could be several explanations for a second authentication prompt including a software error. Just to be sure, you can check the logs at /var/log/auth.log to view all authentication attempts.  If you suspect you have malware or just want to secure Ubuntu further, several tools such as rkhunter, chkrootkit, and various anti-virus programs exist for Linux.

Comment: Before the reinstallation of Linux, I could install Skype only writing my password once, this time, I had to do twice. But are you sure about the second authentication being not being bad? I mean, to be successful, a malicious program must have the access to the root to get total access to a PC (but obviously, I didn't started any strange program here, only got the .deb files from the official websites)

Comment: While I agree on your conclusion (no cause for concern), I'd like to mention that authentication in Ubuntu Software Center makes use of pkexec, not sudo. Think (not 100% sure) it's normal that you need to confirm each time.

Comment: @gunnar-hjalmarsson is correct, Software Center does use pkexec _not_ sudo, my mistake.

Comment: When installing the Skype .deb package, it should not automatically make an icon in the Taskbar.

Comment: Please note that what I mean with "taskbar" is the upper part of the screen (which includes the Time, battery, and the Shutdown button), also, It only appears after starting the program. Sorry about any misunderstanding.

Comment: Looks like I can't edit. So, I tried to look at the auth.log, but I coudn't understand much, so I will try to take a look on Google.

Comment: Well, I tried, but no success. But at leats the PC is not doing anything strange. If you guys want, I can send what happened when I installed Skype from the .log. Since there's no cause for concern and I didn't downloaded anything wrong, I will leave it for tomorrow.